# How to sign WAX transfer transactions automatically?

Tags: signing

I have a WAX cloud wallet. And I have to sign all transactions manually by clicking `Approve` on the modal dialog created by WaxJS.

Is it possible to automate that by calling some API or signing with private key?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you don't want to use the WAX cloud wallet.

Create a real WAX account with the normal EOSIO permission structions, and then you can automate things as you like.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Mattew Darwin. Any idea about this error when trying private/public key to sign the transaction?

`transaction declares authority '{\"actor\":\"XXX\",\"permission\":\"active\"}', but does not have signatures for it under a provided delay of 0 ms, provided permissions [], provided keys`